# OrderBy query - Can I order by the grandchild "Vote" stored in firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to find a way to query by the child node 'votes' to order the data by number of 'votes'. I'm pretty sure because of the way I have stored the data in firebase it cant be queried but I currently have to store it this way.

```
  {
     "45" : {
       "Biological and Ecological" : {
         "Votes" : 1
        }
    },
     "567" : {
       "Technology" : {
         "Votes" : 2
        }
    },
     "620" : {
       "Technology" : {
          "Votes" : 1
        }
  },
     "702" : {
       "Social and Behavioral" : {
          "Votes" : 1
        }

     }
 }
```

I am attempting to order by the child "Votes" is there a way to do this? Below is the method in which it is currently displayed I am aware that .OrderbyChild("Votes") isnt defining the path correctly but is there a way to achieve this?

```
   Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CountLikes/").orderByChild("Votes");

   query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for(DataSnapshot grandchild: child.getChildren()) {
                    arrayList.add("Project " + child.getKey() + "         " + grandchild.getKey() + "        " + (String.valueOf(grandchild.child("Votes").getValue(Long.class)))); 

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }

                }}



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi! "Isn't defining the path correctly but is there a way to achieve this". 
Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on how you're data model is actually set up in the RealtimeDatabase. In this case, there is not a consistent path to the data you're attempting to sort by (different vote types it seems).

If you have something like:

```
CountLikes: [ // collection
    docId: { // document
        typeOfVote: { // map name
            "votes": number // vote count
        }
    }
]
```

The way you are trying to order by the child will be possible if "votes" is split up from "typeOfVote" because right now you can't order by child through a potential wildcard (to get a level deeper than "Technology" for example).

```
CountLikes: [
    docId: {
        "votes": number,
        "type": typeOfVote
    }
]
```

With this, your orderByChild "votes" could *probably* work :)

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CountLikes/").orderByChild("votes")
```

(update)
[This answer by Frank (and read the comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40622320/10747134) shows another example/more info for orderByChild.

Comment: OP is using Firebase Realtime Database, not Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Woops, great catch. Will update the answer in a bit (unless you'd like to answer, I'll remove).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database can query child nodes of a location based on a property, as long as that property is at a known location with a fixed path.

In your case, the child nodes are not at a fixed path (since the `Technology` and `Biological and Ecological` keys are not fixed), so this query is not possible with your current data structure.

To allow the query, restructure your data to turn it into a flat list. For example, this might work:

```
 "45" : {
   "Category": "Biological and Ecological",
   "Votes" : 1
 }
 "567" : {
   "Category": "Technology",
   "Votes" : 2
 },
 "620" : {
   "Category": "Technology",
    "Votes" : 1
 },
 "702" : {
   "Category": "Social and Behavioral",
   "Votes" : 1
 }
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

do you know all the possible values of the property like 'Biological and Ecological'?
then you can just a for loop and select ....gerReference("CountLikes").orderbychild(property[i]+"/votes").....

I Know it's a weird way,
but as you a told you cant change the structure,even I will suggest you to keep another dataset in the db for the values of the property